# vertically align anchor tag

Tags: html, css

I would like to vertically align the icon on the following screenshot with the other elements :

[image]

I was wondering if I could find a little fix without changing the html structure (I didn't develop that code, I am just debugging). I tried with the `vertical-align:middle` property but I didn't manage to fix it.

```
li {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: outside none none;
    margin: 0px 0px 11px;
    padding: 0px;
}

label {
    width:200px;
    float:left;
    padding:8px;
}

select {
    border: 1px solid #CBCBCB;
    float: left;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 318px;
    color: #4F4E4E;
    font-family: lucida sans unicode;
}
```

```
<ul>

    <li>
        <label for="1_selectLangue">
            Langue
            <span style="color:red">*</span>
        </label>

        <select id="1_selectLangue"></select>

        <a id="boutonLangue">
            <img src="ic_enter.png"/>
        </a>

    </li>

</ul>
```

JSFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/aghvyhto/2/

Comment: Where exactly the enter image you want?

Comment: On the screenshot, the image is pushed at the top, I'd like it to be centered (equal padding on bottom and top), vertically centered with the label and the select tags

Comment: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) is always appreciated :)

Comment: `img` tag does not support closing tag, it is an orphan tag. Use like this for xhtml support : `<img />` or if you do not care : `<img>`.

Comment: True, I corrected that! @Zeratops I added the JSFiddle link

Answer (score 1):

Use `display: inline-block;` and `vertical-align: middle;` as well as remove `float: left;` on both **label** and **select**.

```css
ul {
   width:800px;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: outside none none;
  margin: 0px 0px 11px;
  padding: 0px;
}
 
label {
  width:200px;
  /*float: left;*/  /* Remove this. */
  padding:8px;
}
 
select {
  border: 1px solid #CBCBCB;
  padding: 5px;
  /*float: left;*/  /* Remove this. */
  width: 318px;
  color: #4F4E4E;
  font-family: lucida sans unicode;
}

/* Add the following styles. */
li > * {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <label for="1_selectLangue">
      Langue
      <span style="color:red">*</span>
    </label>
    <select id="1_selectLangue"></select>
      <a id="boutonLangue">
        <img src="ic_enter.png"/>
      </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```css
li {
    display: table;/* change display to table */
    list-style: outside none none;
    margin: 0px 0px 11px;
    padding: 0px;
}

label {
    width:200px;
    float:left;
    padding:8px;
}

select {
    border: 1px solid #CBCBCB;
    float: left;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 318px;
    color: #4F4E4E;
    font-family: lucida sans unicode;
}
```

```html
<ul>

 <li>
  <label for="1_selectLangue">
   Langue
   <span style="color:red">*</span>
  </label>

  <select id="1_selectLangue"></select>
<!--add following style to your anchor tag-->
  <a id="boutonLangue" style="display:table-cell;vertical-align:middle">
   <img src="ic_enter.png"/>
  </a>

 </li>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add

```
    #boutonLangue>img{
        position:absolute;
        margin-top: 6px;
    }
```

to your css and it should push the img a little bit down.
[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/aghvyhto/3/) is your modified fiddle.